# find a date in a Dataframe column pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, find

I have column date but I'm not able to find a datetime element in it, even if it exist.
Please see below.

```
x
datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)

pd.to_datetime(date).dt.date
0         2018-01-01
1         2018-01-01
2         2018-01-01
3         2018-01-01
4         2018-01-01
   
997693    2021-01-08
997694    2021-01-08
997695    2021-01-08
997696    2021-01-08
997697    2021-01-08
Name: data, Length: 997698, dtype: object

  
pd.to_datetime(date).dt.date[6]
datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)

x in pd.to_datetime(date).dt.date
False
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer**
To get `True` we have to check values converted to numpy array using `values` method.

```
x = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
x in pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date.values
True
```

**Long answer**

Boolean indexing in for `datetime` in pandas can be applied as below:

Below checks will return `True`

```
'2018-01-01' in df['date'].values

(pd.to_datetime(df.date) == pd.Timestamp("2018.1.1")).any()
(pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date == pd.Timestamp("2018.1.1")).any()

x = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
x in pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date.values

(pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date == x).any()
```

If we want to find dates and print dates from df

**Input**

```
d="""date
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2018-01-01
2021-01-08
2021-01-08"""
df=pd.read_csv(StringIO(d))
df


    date
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-01-01
3   2021-01-08
4   2021-01-08
```

**Any of the below option can be used to find match the dates** - `loc` is preferred

```
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.date) == pd.Timestamp('2018.1.1')]
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.date) == '2018.1.1']
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date == datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)]
df[pd.to_datetime(df.date) == pd.Timestamp('2018.1.1')]
df[pd.to_datetime(df.date) == '2018.1.1']
df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.date == datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)]
```

**Output**

```
    date
0   2018-01-01
1   2018-01-01
2   2018-01-01
```